# Is there a way to customize "HikariPool-k - Starting..." message

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

When springboot starts, it prints following in db config:

```
2022-11-17 10:33:03,608 INFO  [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

Is there a way to give a meaningful name instead of `HikariPool-1`. I have already tried

```
entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("SOME_NAME");
```

But with this approach, I could only see the name if init is success. If init fails, I do not get the name (although error stack is logged and I can debug, that is not the point here)

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple setting.

```
HikariConfig hk = new HikariConfig();
hk.setPoolName("Ahroo");
DataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hk);
```